# How to loop first n folders and their subfolders to read the file in R?

Tags: r

I have a folder with lets say 50 folders, and each of them contain some number of subfolders (only one depth), I need to loop through the first 10 folders, and then loop through every subfolders and read the single file that they contain. I tried to loop using `list.dirs()` but it gives all the subfolders as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general approach would look something like this:

- First, use `top_folders = list.dirs(recursive = FALSE)` to get the main folders.
- To get the 10 first, use e.g. `head(top_folders, n = 10)`.
- Pass this to `list.files()`, with `recursive = TRUE)`.